# switch between onboard graphics and NVIDIA graphics on fly

Tags: linux

I have Intel on board graphics card and Nvidia graphics card in my system.
Two different monitors are connected to both the ports.
During boot time by default all the bot information displays through on board graphics card.

In my BIOS : Primary Display set to PEG and Internal Graphics is ENABLED.

Is there any way that I can switch between both the graphics card on fly?

(i.e. I want to disable on board graphics at boot time and displaying the information through NVIDIA, and after boot on board graphics should be enabled again)

I am using NVIDIA driver.

Please help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching between two graphics card :

After system boot-up , in .cshrc file I unloaded my inbuilt graphics module(Intel graphics card in my case) . by this the display is forced to use the Nvidia graphics module .
unload module command :  " rmmod -f "Intel  module name"

Comment: Ok in this case , when I removed intel kernel module, the system is forced to use Nvidia module for displaying .  After that I am reloading the Intel kernel module.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to switch cards on fly, you need to install [bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

To run your application with the discrete NVIDIA card run in the terminal:

`optirun [options] <application> [application-parameters]`

Example:

`optirun firefox`

Comment: From what I've heard, `primusrun` is more preferable these days.